# How to return Column number from Oracle to Java

Tags: java, oracle

I used the following query to get the number of columns.

```
select count(*) from all_tab_columns where owner='IULPROJECT' and table_name='SUPPLIERS';
```

This query worked in Oracle command line, I got the number 5, but how can I return this number in Java?

In Java:

```
stmt=conn.createStatement();
query="select count(*) from all_tab_columns where owner='IULPROJECT' and table_name='SUPPLIERS' ";
rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
System.out.println(stmt); //<-- what should I put here to get back my number "5" ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return a table with one row and one column as **count(*)** is a group function. So after getting the ResultSet, go to the first row using **next()** and then get the value using **getInt()**

```
stmt=conn.createStatement();
query="select count(*) from all_tab_columns where owner='IULPROJECT' and table_name='SUPPLIERS' ";
rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
rset.next();
System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data are already in `ResultSet` that contains one `column` so you must call first `next()` because `ResultSet` `Cursor` type is implicitly positioned to row before first. So call `next()` method and then with `count = rset.getInt(1)` you will get your data.

```
 rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    int count = 0;
    while (rset.next()) {

    count = rset.getInt(1); // numbering of columns starts from 1 not from 0

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Hope it helps you.
Regards man

Answer (score 1):

```
rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rset.next()) {
    System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rset.getInt(1). It will return the valuse of the first column.

```
while(rset.next){ System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as background info, note that

```
select count(*) from ...
```

will always return exactly one row that will be greater than or equal to zero and which will never be null (the latter being true for all:

```
count(*)
```

calls).

I put this as a comment initially but * = italics and I couldn't find a way of escaping it